# Hex/Dec Program in C getting the wrong output and cant use Scanf

Tags: c

Whenever I run my program, I think that I am getting the wrong output using the included test strings, though I think my first function is working. Tthe files I have are xbits.c xbits.h and two versions of showxbits.c, one that is instructor provided and the other is the one I am trying to use scanf with. The program is supposed to convert an integer to a hex string and then a hex string to an integer. My main problem is, while I think that my code works with the instructor test input, I know it doesn't work with the scanf showxbits because it gives answers such as 0xS when 127 is inputed.

Here is the xbits.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int hex_To_dec(int c) {
        char hex_values[] = "aAbBcCdDeEfF";
        int i;
        int answer = 0;
        for (i=0; answer == 0 && hex_values[i] != '\0'; i++) {
                if (hex_values[i] == c) {
                answer = 10 + (i/2);
                }
        }
        return answer;
}
/* function represents the int n as a hexstring which it places in the
hexstring array */
void itox(char* s, int n)
{
        char *digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        int i=0,j;
        char temp;
        while(n > 0)
        {
                s[i] = digits[n % 16]; 
                n /= 16;
                i++;
        }
        s[i] = '\0'; // Add null terminator
        i--;
        // Now reverse it in place
        for(j=0; j < i / 2; j++)
        {
                temp = s[j];
                s[j] = s[i - j];
                s[i - j] = temp;
        }
}
/* function converts hexstring array to equivalent integer value  */
int xtoi(char hexstring[]) {
        //printf("in xtoi, processing %s\n", hexstring);
        int answer = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int valid = 1;
        int hexit;
        if (hexstring[i] == '0') {
                ++i;
                if (hexstring[i] == 'x' || hexstring[i] == 'X') {
                        ++i;
                }
        }
        while(valid && hexstring[i] != '\0') {
                answer = answer * 16;
                if(hexstring[i] >='0' && hexstring[i] <= '9') {
                        answer = answer + (hexstring[i] - '0');
                }
                else {
                        hexit = hex_To_dec(hexstring[i]);
                        if (hexit == 0) {
                                valid = 0;
                        }
                        else {
                        answer = answer + hexit;
                        }
                }
                ++i;
        }
        if(!valid) {
                answer = 0;
        }
        return answer;
}
```

Here is the showxbits.c provided by the instructor:

```
/*
 *  stub driver for functions to study integer-hex conversions
 *
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "xbits.h"

#define ENOUGH_SPACE 1000 /* not really enough space */

int main() {
  char hexstring[ENOUGH_SPACE];
  int m=0, n = 0x79FEB220;
  itox(hexstring, n);


  /* for stub testing: create a fake input string */
  strcpy(hexstring, "6BCD7890"); 
  m = xtoi(hexstring);

  printf("\t%12d %s %12d\n", n, hexstring, m);

  return 0;  /* everything is just fine */
}
```

And here is the showxbits that has scanf in it:

```
/*
 *  stub driver for functions to study integer-hex conversions
 *
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "xbits.h"

#define ENOUGH_SPACE 100 /* not really enough space */

int main() {
    char hexstring[ENOUGH_SPACE];
    //int m=0, n = 0x79FEB220;
    int n, m;
    while ((scanf("%d", &n)) == 1) {
        itox(hexstring, n);
        m = xtoi( hexstring);
        printf("%12d  %s  %12d\n", n, hexstring, m);
    }

return 0;  /* everything is just fine */
}
```

Like I said, I am getting weird outputs when using the scanf function. I am a complete beginner programmer and would really appreciate any help that can be offered. Thanks!

Comment: It's a quite bunch of code. Start with describing what it should do, what it actually doing, and why it is wrong. Using non-fuzzy terms instead of "weird-outputs".

Comment: Thanks, I edited the intro to include some more information.

Comment: What is that: ` = = 1` in your `main`? Does it compile at all?

Comment: And your comment about  ` /* not really enough space */` is very right. So why `1`? It won't work.

Comment: The == 1 was included in an example that the instructor told us to try when using scanf. And I forgot to edit the 1 in second xbits to see if it would work.  I changed it to 100 and it is still giving the wrong input. It is giving 0x for 127  now.

Comment: Als o yes, the code compiles with no errors

Comment: You seem to be making a 5-course meal out of itox().  You could just index an array: "0123456789ABCDEF" with each nibble.

Comment: Your presented code doesn't contain `==`. It contains `= =`. See the difference? Please update the question with the *actual* code.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I edited the code with the edits I made just now.

Comment: @MartinJames, I'm not really sure what you mean by that.

Comment: This line is funny: `hexstring[i]=hexstring[i];`. Hint: you want `hexstring[i]=hexstring[i] + '0';`

Comment: But as @MartinJames have mentioned, the conversion logic is *very* twisted.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Like I said, I am a complete beginner. Do you have any input on how I can fix the conversion logic?

Comment: [Here](https://ideone.com/E60t96) is my quick implementation, using what @MartinJames proposed.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  wot, no recursion?  :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. I added your code into my xbits.c and I am now getting a segmentation fault

Comment: @MartinJames Not today :)

Comment: @Greg So you are not using it right. The arguments are reversed.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I edited the code and the segmentation fault went away. Now for my output I am getting "127 F7 247" when the input is 127. How can I get the F7 to be the actual hex value of 127 (0x7F).

Comment: It's a bug in my code :) Not reversing correctly. Sorry, have no time to fix it or help you further.

Comment: if, for instance, the user enters '64' the value in hex... is ox04 0x00 0x00.  Which is not quite what is wanted,  the the conversions are called and things go down hill from there including the reverse code is never called.  Strongly suggest using a debugger (like gdb) to step through the code so you can see what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a mistake in the function `itox` , which would cause the wrong result when reverse string. Then, the wrong hexstring from `itox` will result in the abnormal output finally.

The quick fix is to replace `j < i / 2` with `j < i / 2 + 1`

```
void itox(char* s, int n)
{
        //......
        // Now reverse it in place
        for(j=0; j < i / 2 + 1 ; j++)
        {
                temp = s[j];
                s[j] = s[i - j];
                s[i - j] = temp;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reverse the string to convert to hex ascii:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char* hexlat="0123456789ABCDEF";

char *binaryToHex(unsigned int answer, char *result){
  if(answer==0) return result;
  else{
     result=binaryToHex(answer>>4,result);
    *result=hexlat[answer & 0x0F];
    return result+1;
  }
};

int main(void) {
    unsigned int answer=0x12340ADF;
    char hexAnswer[32];
    *binaryToHex(answer,hexAnswer)='\0';
    printf("%s",hexAnswer);
    return 0;
}
```